# window.print() in same window vs new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can any one help with this .

Case 1: Print in same window.

```
var restorepage = $('body').html();
var printcontent = 
$('#ctl00_WebPartManager_BlankWP0_CanvasControl_Canvas').clone();

$('body').empty().html(printcontent);
window.print();
$('body').html(restorepage);
```

Output: This is perfect for me , the only thing is after i restore the original controls they dont seem to work . So I am trying to print the same using a new window.
[image]

Case 2: Print in a New window

```
    var w = window.open();
    var printcontent = $('#ctl00_WebPartManager_BlankWP0_CanvasControl_Canvas').clone();
    $(w.document.body).empty().html(printcontent);
    w.focus();
    w.print();
    w.close();
```

Output : The Images are realigned and even image goes missing.
I need the Case1 Output , but in a new window , so as the original window is not modified.
[image]

Comment: Perhaps your working version relies on external stylesheets or relative paths that don't resolve properly in the new window?

Comment: i just want new window to print the contents i cloned

Comment: I understand your intent, I'm trying to figure our your problem. Sometimes copying *just the body* is not sufficient. If you have an element, for example, `<img src="/images/my_image.jpg">`, and then you try to use that same exact code on a page in a totally different directory, that image won't work any longer because the relative URL is no longer correct. Similarly, if you have `class="my-class"`, and the definition of `.my-class` comes from an external stylesheet, but then you open a new window that doesn't include that stylesheet, it will not have the `.my-class` style applied.

Comment: ya correct ... will it work if i create an iframe and print it

Answer (score 0):

Yo need create a partial view with all css references and then clone the object in the new window, or maybe you can create an iFrame or dialog in the same page...